# Run bash text scripts after docker run

Tags: django, linux, bash, docker

I have django application, a test.sh script and dockerfile. I have built dockerfile and run it by `docker run -d -p 80:80 IMAGE_NAME`.
Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget
RUN apt install gunicorn3 -y

COPY ./ ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x ./test.sh

CMD ["sh", "test.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 core.wsgi:application"]
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py test
```

Gunicorn is running successfully. Now I want to run test.sh script with `docker run -it --rm IMAGE_NAME test.sh`. When i run that command the server runs but never executes test.sh but gunicorn server runs.
How can I run test.sh from `docker run -it --rm IMAGE_NAME test.sh`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to run the tests while building? For example, you may have a problem with connecting to the database if it is running in a different container.

Comment: Typically, if you need to run two processes, you'd run them in two separate containers.  You can use the same image for both and that's fine.  The `docker run IMAGE_NAME ./test.sh` syntax will only work if you change `gunicorn` to be the image's `CMD` and don't have an `ENTRYPOINT` (I'd recommend doing this).  Don't forget to break the command into multiple words inside the JSON array `["gunicorn", "--bind", ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you trying to run a script on running container have you tried `docker exec -it container_id bash < mylocal.sh`?